# Dynamic UITableViewHeader View with Label

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView` in .`xib` file which I'm loading at runtime and setting it as tableHeaderView of `UITableView`. I have a `UILabel` in my xib file which can grow dynamically with fixed `UIButton` at bottom.

If I set the width of `UILabel` to fixed width it works.

[image]

If I set the Leading/Trailing on `UILabel` then it doesn't work :(
[image]

I'm using the below code to handle the height of headerView

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

// Dynamic sizing for the header view
if (table.tableHeaderView) {
    UIView *headerView = table.tableHeaderView;
    float height = [headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    CGRect headerFrame = headerView.frame;

    // If we don't have this check, viewDidLayoutSubviews() will get
    // repeatedly, causing the app to hang.
    if (height != headerFrame.size.height) {
        headerFrame.size.height = height;
        headerView.frame = headerFrame;
        table.tableHeaderView = headerView;
    }

}
```

}

Anybody can explain why setting the leading/trailing is not working?
My view with constraint is like (without fixed width):

[image]

Comment: Have you set numberOfLines = 0 for label?

Comment: Obviously it works. First add your constraints then only we can identify what is the issue.

Comment: can you show your whole code?

Comment: @VishalSonawane yes did that. Constraints already there, added the image. My class don't have any more code just 1 more method to set the text into label.

Comment: hi @Husyn i was having the exact situation. And i have solved it by setting constraints properly. I had an issue because of adding wrong constraint as 'centre vertically with superview' for button.
please check once are your constraints proper

Answer (score 0):

call in the end of viewDidLayoutSubviews.

[viewWithLabelAndButton setNeedLayout];
[viewWithLabelAndButton layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: I suppose to you to do creation of UIView programmatically, because may be this case - bug of xib, but i see that your constraints installed right. 

Another case to try - increase height of superview UILabel in xib. Apple use interesting mechanism in xib and views don't each time get a good size. God luck!